# Hexa to binary to decimal (floating point representation-normalized)

Tags: floating-point, precision

I tried to convert hexa to binary using floating-point representation(normalized form) , 
eg.3F800000=001111111000000..... 0=sign(+ve) bit, 01111111=expo(8 bit), 0000.....=mantissa(23 bit). 
Now I want to convert to decimal, what is the procedure for this example? 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the exponent to decimal: 127.
2. Subtract the bias, 127: Final exponent 0.
3. Because it is a normal number, the significand, in binary, is 1.0000...0000
4. Convert the significand to decimal: 1.0
5. Multiply by 2<sup>0</sup>: 1.0
6. The sign bit is 0, so do not negate: 1.0

The final result is 1.0